# How does dp has fixed value to measure size?

Tags: android, units-of-measurement

How does Density-independent pixel `dip` used to measure size and it assumed that 
`dip = 160 dpi` and dpi has not fixed size    ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dp is always 1/160 inches.  The dpi of the phone can be anything (although certain values are more common than others).  WHen calculating how many pixels big 1 dp is, the formula is dpi/160.

Comment: what this `how many pixels big 1 dp is` mean ?